# How do I optimize this piece of C# code so that it doesn't take too long to run?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, substring

The assignment is:

> Given two arrays of strings determine whether corresponding elements contain a common substring

My code is (the method is given, I should fill it in):

```cs
public static void commonSubstring(List<string> a, List<string> b) { 
    string[] listA = a.ToArray(); 
    string[] listB = b.ToArray(); 
    bool contains = false;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < listA.Length; i++)
    {
        foreach(char c in listA[i])
        {
            foreach (char d in listB[i]) {
                if (c == d) {
                    contains = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (contains) { break; }
        }
        if (contains == true) {
            Console.WriteLine("YES");
            contains = false;
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

It gets through most test cases, but in some it says that it takes too long (above 3 seconds) to run, so when there are large inputs. Does anyone have any idea how I can optimize this code to make it faster so that it takes less than 3 seconds to calculate with large inputs? So basically it prints a YES if `a[i]` and `b[i]` have a character in common and NO if they don't.

Comment: Finding the common substring is a *tough* problem. You'll have to look at the various algorithms and implementations and pick one. The brute force approach is too slow.

Comment: Certainly not the bottleneck, but why are you creating array copies of the lists you receive? Just iterate the original parameters.

Comment: This is a set intersection problem, O(n) complexity instead of O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

There is no escaping the fact that something needs to happen for every pair of `listA[i], listB[i]`, that's not the issue. But take a good look at these nested loops:

> ```
> foreach(char c in listA[i])
> {
>     foreach (char d in listB[i]) {
>         if (c == d) {
>             contains = true;
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>     if (contains) { break; }
> }
> ```

You have already discovered that we really only need to find a letter that is in both string, and then we have a common substring of length 1 (there may be a longer common substring, but it is irrelevant for this problem, as we only need to know whether it exists - you should *not* use a "longest common substring" algorithm, that's complete overkill). It was done by comparing every combination of characters. However, there is an alternative:

Make a HashSet with the characters from string A. For every character in string B, check whether it is in that HashSet.

The number of operations goes from the *products* of the lengths of the string, to the *sum* of the length of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically it prints a YES if a[i] and b[i] have a character in
> common and NO if they don't.

you can optimize it by omitting the nested loop

```
public static void commonSubstring(List<string> a, List<string> b)
    {
        string[] listA = a.ToArray();
        string[] listB = b.ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < listA.Length; i++)
        {
            if (HaveCharInCommon(listA[i], listB[i]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YES");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO");
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool HaveCharInCommon(string a, string b)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<char>(a);
        foreach (var ch in b)
        {
            if (set.Contains(ch))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a O(n*log n) version of finding out if the strings have characters (substrings) in common:

```
Input: s1 s2  
let ss1 = sort s1 (O(N log N)  
let ss2 = sort s2 (O(N log N)  
let l1 = length s1 (O(1) in C#, O(N) in C...)  
let l2 = length s2   
let i1 = 0, i2 = 0  
while (i1 < l1 and i2 < l2)  
{ 
  if ss1[i1] == ss2[i2]  
  then return true  
  if ss1[i1] < ss2[i2]  
  then i1++, continue  
  if ss1[i1] > ss2[i2]  
  then i2++, continue  
}
return false
```

The total complexity is O(N log N) (the sorting complexity).
I don't have C# on my system, so I apologize I have to give you an implementation
in another language instead.

```lisp
(defun common-sub-string-p (s1 s2)
       (let ((s1-sorted (sort s1 #'char-lessp))
             (s2-sorted (sort s2 #'char-lessp))
             (l1 (length s1))
             (l2 (length s2)))
         (labels ((compute (i1 i2)
            (if (and (< i1 l1) (< i2 l2))
                (let ((c1 (aref s1-sorted i1))
                      (c2 (aref s2-sorted i2)))
                  (cond 
                      ((eql c1 c2) t)
                      ((char-lessp c1 c2) (compute (1+ i1) i2))
                      ((char-lessp c2 c1) (compute i1 (1+ i2)))))
                nil)))
           (compute 0 0))))
```

There are plenty more ways to do this. For example, you could create 2 bit sets, use the characters of the strings as indices and then with 1 bit set for each of the 2 strings, test if they have a common subset.

If the strings are restricted to ascii encoding (0..127), those bit sets could be an array of 16 bytes (or 2 uint64), where each bit in the bytes represents the existence of a respective character.

With that, you have to loop over each character in the strings (O(N)), then do a bitwise and of the 2 resulting bit sets and if that is not zero, they have common sub strings.

Hence, the best you can get is probably O(N) for ascii strings.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int common_chars(const char* s1, const char *s2) {
  uint64_t bitset1[2] = {0,0};
  uint64_t bitset2[2] = {0,0};
  size_t l1,l2;
  l1 = strlen(s1);
  l2 = strlen(s2);
  
  for(size_t i = 0; i < l1; ++i) {
    char c = s1[i];
    if (c < 64) {
      bitset1[0] |= 1 << c;
    } else {
      bitset1[1] |= 1 << (c-64);
    }
  }
  for(size_t i = 0; i < l2; ++i) {
    char c = s2[i];
    if (c < 64) {
      bitset2[0] |= 1 << c;
    } else {
      bitset2[1] |= 1 << (c-64);
    }
  }
  if ( ((bitset1[0] & bitset2[0]) == 0)
       && ((bitset1[1] & bitset2[1]) == 0)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  if (argc >= 3) {
    printf ("%s <-> %s : %s\n", argv[1],argv[2],
        (common_chars(argv[1],argv[2])? "true" : "false"));
  } else {
    puts("you need to give 2 strings as command line arguments.");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a pro at C#. But the mainly problem is the nested loop. The time complexity of Three level nested loop with be ***O(n^3)***.

```
public class Program{
public static void Main()
{
    string[] listA = {"apple", "banana", "orange", "test"};
    string[] listB = {"NOD", "train", "warship"}; 
    bool contains = false;
    
    //For preventing Array out of bound
    int length = (listA.Length > listB.Length) ? listA.Length : listB.Length;
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        string longer = "";
        string shorter = "";
        
        //Find the shorter string for minimizing the looping time. 
        if(listA[i].Length > listB[i].Length) {
            longer = listA[i];
            shorter = listB[i];
        } else {
            shorter = listA[i];
            longer = listB[i];
        }
        
        foreach(char a in shorter){
            if(longer.Contains(a.ToString())) {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        
        if (contains) {
            Console.WriteLine("YES");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("NO");
        }
        contains = false;
    }
}}
```